# Forwarding reference and argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

I'm trying to understand perfect forwarding a bit deeply and faced a question I can't figure out myself.
Suppose this code:

```
void fun(int& i) {
  std::cout << "int&" << std::endl;
}

void fun(int&& i) {
  std::cout << "int&&" << std::endl;
}

template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& i) {
  fun(i);
}

int main()
{
    wrapper(4);
}
```

It prints `int&`. To fix this one should use std::forward. That's clear. What is unclear is why it is so.
What the code above unwraps into is:

```
void fun(int & i)
{
  std::operator<<(std::cout, "int&").operator<<(std::endl);
}


void fun(int && i)
{
  std::operator<<(std::cout, "int&&").operator<<(std::endl);
}


template <typename T>
void wrapper(T&& i) {
  fun(i);
}

/* First instantiated from: insights.cpp:21 */
#ifdef INSIGHTS_USE_TEMPLATE
template<>
void wrapper<int>(int && i)
{
  fun(i);
}
#endif


int main()
{
  wrapper(4);
  return 0;
}
```

So `i` should have rvalue type of `int&&`. The question is: why do I need std::forward here since compiler already knows that `i` is `int&&` not `int&` but still calls `fun(it&)`?

Comment: I don't remember exactly where I read it (probably somewhere here on SO), but it was something like "Whatever has a name is an lvalue". In your case, in the `wrapper` function the variable `i` "has a name" so it's an lvalue and thus will be using the lvalue reference overload of `fun`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Types and [value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) are different things.

> Each C++ expression (an operator with its operands, a literal, a variable name, etc.) is characterized by two independent properties: a type and a value category.

`i`, the name of the variable, is an lvalue expression, even the variable's type is rvalue-reference.

> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> - the name of a variable, ... Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression;
> - ...

That's why we should use [`std::forward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) to preserve the original value category of a [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) argument.

Comment: Underrated answer! There is a [note in the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.lval#4) that elaborates this even in more detail. You should maybe be a little bit more precise in the language in my opinion. "As a named variable, `i` is an lvalue" is technically inprecise. A variable (whatever that means) has no value category. Only the expression "`i`" has a value category - which is lvalue.

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

> why do I need `std::forward` here since compiler already knows that i is
> `int&&` not `int&` but still calls `fun(it&)`?

The type of `i` is `int&&`, but `i` itself is an *lvalue*. So when you're calling `fun(i)`, since `i` itself is an *lvalue*, the compiler will choose `fun(int &)`.

If you want to invoke `fun(int &&)`, you can use `std::move` to cast it to an rvalue

```
fun(std::move(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

> why do I need std::forward here since compiler already knows that i is int&& not int& but still calls fun(it&)?

Because `i` when used as/in an expression such as the call `fun(i)` is an **lvalue**. That is the value category of `i` when used as/in an expression is `lvalue`. Thus the call `fun(i)` selects the first overload(`void fun(int&)`).

On the other hand, the **declared type** of `i` is `int&&` i.e., an rvalue reference to `int`.