# A lvalue reference can bind to a rvalue reference but cannot bind to the result of std::move

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, rvalue, stdmove

I have a function that has a lvalue reference as argument, and I found that I can also pass
a rvalue reference to it. However, when I passing the result of `std::move` to the function, I get an error which tells me that I cannot bind non-const lvalue reference to an rvalue.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void foo(T& a) { }

struct A {
    std::string s;
};

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
    A a{"a"};
    A&& ra = std::move(a); 
    foo(ra);            // OK
    foo(std::move(a));  // Error
    return 0;
}
```

I was thinking that `std::move` also returns a rvalue reference.
What is the difference between using an intermediate rvalue reference as argument and directly using the result of `std::move` as argument?

Comment: `ra` is an **lvalue expression** when used in `foo(ra);`

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603035/c-11-rvalue-reference-variables) covers a little of the territory. Somewhat counterintuitively, `ra` is _still_ an lvalue--after all, it has a name, and it's valid to put it on the left hand side of an `=`.

Comment: In the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71968902/forwarding-reference-and-argument-deduction/71968945#71968945) it is explained that `ra` is the name of a variable and is an lvalue expression.

Comment: The first thing to understand that [expressions can't have reference types](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1). When a function returns `T &&`, the actual result of the call has type `T`, and "xvalue" value category. (Similarly, returning `T &` gives an lvalue, and returning non-reference gives a prvalue). But standalone rvalue references (unlike ones returned from a function) don't impose the "xvalue" value category. Like all other variables, they are lvalues. (Or rather, expressions consisting of a variable name are lvalues.)

Answer (score 0):

`ra` is a named variable.  As such, it is an lvalue and can be bound to an lvalue reference.

`std::move(a)` returns a `A&&`, but that returned value is a prvalue.  lvalue references cannot bind to prvalues.